# 今のデザインは読みにくくありませんか？

Tags: 討議, デザイン

本家もかなり酷いですけど、視認性わるくないですか？
どうもQ&AサイトってろくでもないUIが多い気がします。

- https://teratail.com/（パッと見の見てくれだけは良い）
- http://w3q.jp/（横幅狭すぎ）

具体的には

1. 構成要素の区切り境界線がない、または曖昧すぎ
2. 画像・アイコンが適切に利用されてない
3. 行間隔おかしい

「そもそも読みにくくて使いたいと思わない」と感じます。
どう思います？平気ですか？

Comment: 流行らないと思う、というよりは、「〜〜は良くないと感じるのですがどうでしょうか？」と言った方が改善されやすくなると思います。良くないと思ったのでしたら、悪い所が改善される為に言い方を工夫してみて、問題提起してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: UIの問題に焦点を絞るようにタイトル・本文を編集しました

Answer (score 3):

「1. 構成要素の区切り境界線がない、または曖昧すぎ」に関しまして．

全体としては @tomute さんの仰るようにすっきりとした印象で，特に見づらいと感じたことはありませんが，回答と回答の間については[本家 stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)  のように境界線が入るほうが（より）みやすいように思います．

Answer (score 2):

スタックオーバーフローの魅力は、誰でも積極的に編集・運営に参加することが出来る点が魅力です。  
[投票サイトのような質問](https://teratail.com/questions/4283)や[課題の丸投げ](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14139798364)が排除できる。点があります。

視認性については確かにコメントが多い場合について回答までが遠くなることが確認できますが、[５コメントほどで折りたたまれている](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file)ようです。

他の問題点として言語の偏り(利用者の偏り)や利用者レベルの偏り、が確認できます。流行りの学生プログラマやマイコンプログラマなど初学者の割合が少ないのは、敷居が高いというイメージがあるのでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

慣れの問題もあるかも知れませんが、特に視認性が悪いと感じたことはないですね。
「1. 構成要素の区切り境界線がない、または曖昧すぎ」に関しては、逆にスッキリしたデザインになるので悪くないと感じています（欧米のスタイルは図表などで罫線を最小限にするので、それと同じ理屈かなと）。

Comment: 類似の項目についてなのでここにぶら下げます．全体としての印象としては「スッキリ」というのに同意なのですが，個人的には回答と回答の間の境界については本家 stackoverflow.com のように何かしらの区切りがあったほうが見やすいと感じます．見にくくて仕方がないとは思わない程度ですけれど．

Comment: 気づいてませんでしたが、本家の方は回答と回答の間に境界線が入ってますね。区切りがあったほうが見やすいというのは確かにそうですね。ぜひ、本質問の回答として改善を提案していただければと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます，投稿いたしました．

Comment: 改善提案ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

行間に関しては私も改善の余地があると思います。具体的には、投稿本文はもっと行間を広げてよいと思います。

現在のCSSで

```
.post-text {
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

となっているところを、1.5emにしてよいかと思います。

> 「TrueTypeフォント パーフェクトコレクション」によれば、欧文の行間（レディング）はフォント・サイズの２０％くらいでOKだそうですが、和文の場合は５０％、もしくは７５％くらいが適切だそうです。  
>   ([ソース](http://waviaei.com/2006/07/11/separate-japanese-lang-css-settings/))
>
> 日本語のテキストでは一般的にフォントサイズの1.5倍が読みやすい行の高さとされている。
>   ([ソース](http://www.webdesignleaves.com/wp/htmlcss/445/))

例として、複数行にわたる段落は少し詰まった感じがします:

私は今よくこの関係者という点の時に向っますでしょ。いくらでも毎日で徴顔はことにこの尊敬ましょですかもを与えているですがは修養するずですから、こうにも云っあっあるですまし。expectsを云うです訳はついに前の初めてないますある。ほとんど張君で乱暴個人どう尊敬をしあり哲学この国家私か留学にというお増減でですますなて、その偶然もそれか大学生徒に云いから、嘉納さんの事に風俗のいつにとにかくお威圧とありてそれ道具でお遠慮に飲んようにひとまず大観察に利くたありて、けっしてつい挨拶で命じますがいるた気から考えるですなけれ。

([私の環境でのスクリーンショット](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulcuf.png))

また、入れ子のリストの行間も調整の余地があると思います。

- いろは

  - にほへと ("いろは" との間隔がせまい)
  - ちりぬるを ("にほへと" との間隔が広い)
- わかよ

  - たれそ
  - つねならむ

([私の環境でのスクリーンショット](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIRoo.png))

環境: Google Chrome / Mac OS X 10.10 (retina)

Comment: スクリーンショットは現状を撮ったものと思って良いですか？（最初段落の方は、ためしに 1.5emにしたバージョンにしたものかなと思ってしまったので。）

Comment: @fliedonion はい、現状を撮ったものです。分かりにくいのでスクリーンショットはリンクにとどめるように編集します